# Transform column to number of minutes

Tags: r, lubridate, posixct

I have to compare 2 columns: X1-X2

X1=  in this format = "%H:%M:%S" (01:50:00,02:30:00, 02:15:00....)

X2= is just total number of minutes like this ( 15,50,150,)

I used this code to transform the X2 column but it give me NA

```
as.POSIXct(X2, format = "%H:%M:%S")
```

the X1 and X2 both character now
Any  help??

Comment: @akrun, thank you but I got this  error Error: All arguments must be numeric or NA
> and when I transform it to numeric with as.numeric I got NA values..

Answer (score 0):

library(lubridate)

df$x2<- hm(df$x1, quiet = TRUE)

df$x2<- hour(df$x1)*60 + minute(df$x1)